# ClassNotFoundException trown when registering Midlet in the PushRegistry

Tags: java-me, push, classnotfoundexception, midlet

I'm getting an odd error I can't get to the bottom of. When I register the midlet in the Push Registry it throws the ClassNotFoundException. I've used a very standard implementation straight from the API documentation just the url has been altered

```
//  MIDlet class name
String midletClassName = this.getClass().getName();
//  Register a static connection.
String url = "sms://:2049";
//  Use an unrestricted filter.
String filter = "*";
PushRegistry.registerConnection(url, midletClassName, filter);
```

this for some reason throws the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException! When I view the JAD it looks ok:

```
MIDlet-1: AlarmHandler, ,sweoch.test.AlarmHandler
```

which is the class midletClassName equals at debug. So why is this trowing exceptions?

Comment: have you tested it with class name copied from jad and hardcoded into parameter? like this: `PushRegistry.registerConnection(url, "sweoch.test.AlarmHandler", filter)`

Comment: yes and still no luck. I might have refractored the project though and added the Package (sweoch.test) but why would this effect the push registry?

Comment: I've now narrowed it down to the Emulator Platform I'm using **Nokia S40 DP 2.0 SDK 1.1** which throws the class not found, if I run the standard  **Java Micro Edition SDK 3.0** it seems to work fine

Comment: did you check contents of jar file you deploy to Nokia? is `sweoch.test.AlarmHandler.class` file present in the jar?

Comment: The JAR has the Class in the manifest and in the structure when I open it in Netbeans
`MIDlet-1: AlarmHandler, ,sweoch.test.AlarmHandler`

so it's not that...

Comment: not netbeans nor manifest - could you open and browse it like you would do to a reqular zip archive file? and check folder sweoch/test to see if file called AlarmHandler.class is there or not?